# Array equal to itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example:

```
  Var Ape = 1;
    Var Banana = 5;
    Ape = Ape + Banana;
    document.write(Ape)
```

// = Ape equal it self + Banana(5) = 6.

That was fun and simple, now how do you do the exact same thing except with arrays? Like a translation of the above in "array language" for dummies like me.

```
Demonstration Example(not correct):
ape.banana= [10];
var gorilla = 5;
ape.banana[0] = ape.banana[0] + gorilla;
document.write(ape.banana[0])
```

// ape.banana[0] equals itself + gorilla(5) =  15

What is the easiest way and what is the best way?

Comment: `ape.banana[] = 10;` is incorrect syntax. It should be `ape.banana = [10];` for `ape.banana[0]` to be `10`. The rest of your code is correct.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll edit and fix that, I'm tired, but that isn't what made me type that bit of code incorrect :P. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function array_plus_int(array, int) {
    array = array.slice(0); // clone it
    array[0] += int;
    return array;
}
var ape = [ 10 ];
var banana = 5;
ape = array_plus_int(ape, banana);
document.write(ape);
```

You can't override default math operators in JavaScript, so instead of `Ape = Ape + Banana` you can do `Ape = plus(Ape, Banana)`.

Now how you add an integer to an array is up to you. I've added a sample implementation.

It seems like a strange implementation to me. Perhaps you want `Ape` to be an object or a monad instead of an array?

Example:

```
function create_ape() {
    var bananas = 0;
    return {
        give_bananas: function (num_bananas) {
            bananas += num_bananas;
        },
        get_num_bananas: function () {
            return bananas;
        }
    };
}

var ape = create_ape();
ape.give_bananas(5);
document.write(ape.get_num_bananas());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I'm trying to solve, should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
var ape = {banana: [10]};
var gorilla = 5;
ape.banana[0] = ape.banana[0] + gorilla;
document.write(ape.banana[0])
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. You can print the `ape` object to verify its content.

Comment: Yes that worked, you guys make it seem too easy :P thanks
@nash_ag yeah sorry, my bad, I didn't see that you changed the above line, my vision is getting blurry as my eyes are getting tired :P

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way of doing this would be to use the [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) operator `+=`.

```
var ape = { banana: [10] }, gorilla = 5;
document.write(ape.banana[0] += gorilla);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are used to store similar things together.

If you need to store different things together, we'll need an object.

Since bananas and apes are different things, we'll probably need an object.
Apes **have** bananas. So if there are many apes and many gorillas, it would be nice if we made an array for each. Let's also assign a number to each ape since there are more than one.

```
var apes = [];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  tempApe = {};
  tempApe.no = i + 1;
  tempApe.bananas = 2 * i;
}
//let there be a gorilla with 5 bananas
var gorilla = {bananas : 4};

//Adding apes.bananas and gorillas doesn't make sense
//Let's add bananas of ape number 2 and our only gorilla

var totalBananas = apes[1].bananas + gorilla.bananas;
```